# Digital signature using X.509 certificate

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I have a SHA256withRSA **X.509** certificate which is contained in a SmartCard. I need to use it to sign documents in Java generating a P7M (CAdES) envelope. So far I've found some examples of signing documents but the problem is that:

- Most examples use just PDF (such as itext libraries) but I need to
  sign also other documents such as .doc
- Signing examples use a    keystore or private key.But I have *just* the
  X.509 certificate. I    suppose the key is embodied in the X.509
  certificate

Do you have any pointers to get started ? I'm quite confused and cannot find a starting point. 
Thanks!

Comment: You can't have just the certificate. You must also have a keypair. Otherwise you don't have a private key and you can't digitally sign anything.

Answer (score 0):

1.) You can sign any file by using the `byte[]` of the file. This will be a binary signature. It works on any file (.html, .txt, .pdf, .doc, ..).

As comparison to your mentioned "signatures of PDFs", these signatures are called [PAdES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAdES) signatures. These signatures are being recognized by certain applications, like the Adobe Acrobat. If you open such a PDF with the appropriate application, the application will inform you that the document is signed.
But the applications can not do that if you use binary signatures - but at least you can sign everything.

2.) You need a private key in order to sign something. A [X.509][2} certificate only contains the public part of the public-private keypair. The private part must be kept in secret. In your case the private part of the key is stored on the smart card.

Read the manual of the smart card in order to use it.
If you do not understand how the public/private key work, go ahead and read [something about PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure).